# Issue with aws credential for REST API in GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, github-actions, amazon-ses

I have have rest api written in Go which uses AWS SES to send email. When I deploy the api locally using docker the email is getting send through SES in localhost environment. Now I have written integration test for the api, which works perfectly in local system, also the aws credential that is required is placed at default location that is `".aws/credential"`. I have the placed source code in github repo. I want this integration test to get execute for every PR that is raised, for which I have set github action too. All api works in github except the one uses AWS SES, as it doesn't have the aws credential available. I have tried couple of ways to provide aws creds in github without exposing them, but nothing worked so far. Hence need some help on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application can't locate the credentials because **it is stored in your host's `.aws/credential` path, not within your container**.

There are several solutions available to resolve this particular issue, one of them is by simply mounting the `.aws/credential` from your host to your docker container.

If you are using `docker run` command, use `-v`:

```
docker run -v ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro  ...
```

or if you are using docker-compose, specify the path mapping under `volume`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: your_image
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/.aws/credentials:/root/.aws/credentials:ro
```

However, the above solution is not the best one to use, it is risky from a security perspective.

I recommend passing the credentials as environment variables instead.